# Upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS fails

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

I run into the same error over and over when I tried up upgrade to 20.04 LTS.

I'm stuck with this LXD Error, can't redo, uninstall or update my system :-/

Error Message:

```
==> Installing the LXD snap from the 4.0 track for ubuntu-18.04
error: requested a non-existing branch on 4.0/stable for snap "lxd":
       ubuntu-18.04
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/lxd_1%3a0.9_all.deb (--unpack):
 new lxd package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/lxd_1%3a0.9_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Bernhard

Comment: Please provide more information. What error you get when you try to  uninstall lxd ?

Comment: Hello, it's running in a error asking for trying "apt --fix-broken install" and that lead's to the same error as above

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try the below and see if that works.

```
sudo apt purge lxd lxd-client
sudo do-release upgrade
```

Comment: Great, thank you that did help me to get rid of that LXD error :-)

Comment: No worries, if you could please mark above post as the solution, it would be appreciated :)

Comment: @quadcoretoaster I think the correct command should be "do-release-upgrade".